# What steps does a browser use to layout a web page

Tags: html, browser, layout

I'm getting into HTML right now and today I'm learning about page layout.  I want to understand the algorithm that the browser uses to lay out a web page so that I can better anticipate where a `div` will show up based upon my HTML.

I understand that:

- There are block-like elements and span-like elements.
- Block-like elements take up as much vertical space as needed and by default all horizontal space.

  - If you add float styling or absolute positioning, then a div takes up as much horizontal space as needed or you can optionally set a width value.
- Span-like elements take up only as much space as needed.

Where I begin to become unclear is what happens when I start using the `clear:both`, or when nested divs are involved.

I think what I'm looking for is a notion of a ***cursor*** that the browser uses as it lays out the document.  **If such a notion exists, then could you explain how it works.  Otherwise please point me information that you feel will be helpful.**

For the sake of simplicity, assume a simple model for HTML objects - only width and height, nor margins or padding, etc.

Comment: What you refer to as "Span-like elements" are in fact _inline_ elements, which should clarify their behavior a little — in effect, they behave like (parts of) lines of text. As for the block elements, I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: There are a lot of easy to follow tutorials on HTML, and HTML itself is quite easy to pick up. I think you would understand easier by trying than by being explained.

Comment: That said, you may want to look at the Gecko reference. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko

Comment: I was just about to send you to the Gecko reference as well, but as @zneak has already done that, I'll give you this link instead: http://www.mozilla.org/newlayout/doc/layout-2006-12-14/master.xhtml. It's the slides from a talk on the Gecko layout engine.

Comment: This article is really really good. https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/understanding-layout-algorithms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an actual cursor, although browsers may internally use something like that. There are a lot of rules (search for 'Box Model', or even better, '[Visual Formatting Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#visual-model-intro)') that determine how pages should be displayed. 
You are right that there are blocks and inline elements. Blocks do indeed take up all horizontal space unless specified otherwise. They size vertically, unless specified otherwise. That fact should answer your question about the nested divs too.

As far as I can tell, you do have some basic understanding, which is about right too. But instead of pasting the entire documentation about all (incompatible!) versions of the box model here, I think it's best to find some information about it, starting on the [w3.com](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) website.

Comment: You might have noticed that both links I gave link to a chapter from the document you find here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cover.html#minitoc That article is appropriately called "Cascading Style Sheets Level 2 Revision 1 (CSS 2.1) Specification". :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that the next step is to read into the differences between fixed, relative and absolute positioning of elements. The use of float and clear affects each scenario differently and so it is importnat to know how each positioning works.

[Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/) has some very useful information around this subject.